# Count multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i need to count a multidimensional array, but with some rules.

My array is this:

```
<?$array[$iddom][$idrisp][$idopt][$iddoc][$idut]=$text;?>
```

and i have for example this values:

```
[1][1][0][0][31248]=
[1][1][0][0][46619]=
[2][4][0][0][31248]=
[2][5][0][0][46619]=
[3][6][1][0][31248]=
[3][6][3][0][46619]=
[3][7][3][0][31248]=
[3][7][2][0][46619]=
[3][8][1][0][31248]=
[3][8][1][0][46619]=
[4][9][0][0][46619]=
[4][11][0][0][31248]=
[5][13][5][0][31248]=
[5][13][6][0][46619]=
[5][14][4][0][31248]=
[5][14][4][0][46619]=
[5][15][6][0][31248]=
[5][15][5][0][46619]=
[6][0][7][6][31248]=
[6][0][7][6][46619]=
```

if i want to count only a part of array, i use this code:

```
<?$count=array_sum(array_map("count", $array[$key]));?>
```

in this case count is correct

```
[2][4][0][0][31248]=
[2][5][0][0][46619]=
```

the result of count is 2

but in this case the result is 1

```
[1][1][0][0][31248]=
[1][1][0][0][46619]=
```

how i can count dinamically arrays multidimensional?
because in anothe case i need to count for example another level of array, like this:

```
<?$count=array_sum(array_map("count", $array[$key][$key2]));?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap these functions:

```
$count = count(iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                 new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)
         )));
```

Replace `$array` with whichever key you want to apply the count to, like `$array[$key][$key2]`.

Comment: finally i find the sign :)